# Hadoop - copy dataset from external to HDFS directly

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

I'm trying to use distcp to copy a ~500 MB gzipped file to HDFS but get connect timed out error:

```
hadoop distcp  hftp://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.gz hdfs://namenode/some/hdfs/dir
```

Heres the complete error:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem.openConnection(HftpFileSystem.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem$LsParser.fetchList(HftpFileSystem.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem$LsParser.getFileStatus(HftpFileSystem.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem.getFileStatus(HftpFileSystem.java:505)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:64)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:272)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:151)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1715)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.GlobbedCopyListing.doBuildListing(GlobbedCopyListing.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createInputFileListing(DistCp.java:429)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.prepareFileListing(DistCp.java:91)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:181)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:143)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:493)

Whats the right way to copy such large files to HDFS? I'm using CDH 5.14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

hadoop distcp s3a://hwdev-examples-ireland/datasets /tmp/datasets2

Comment: Thanks, but I get "s3.amazonaws.com: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided..." error.

Comment: @user2727704, you can specify your aws creds in core-site.xml, check this https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7165/how-to-copy-hdfs-file-to-aws-s3-bucket-hadoop-dist.html